# could not retrieve utf8 encoding value from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I've such a problem , first take a look at mysql table =>

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
id int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(40) CHARSET utf8 COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
surname VARCHAR(40) CHARSET utf8 COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
);
```

It is storing data successfully , but when I'm trying to retrieve this info to my .php file (which encoding is also utf8) it still showing me question marks (?????), why ? How can I solve it ?

**UPDATE**

Something I'm not doing well. So I've 2 php files, one is classA.php file in which I've defined class which is retrieving info from database and I've included this file (classA.php) into my default.php file where I want to see data.
I've exactly same table which is written above , and I'm writing

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

in the first line in default.php, but it still doesn't work, thanks for advices :))

**SECOND UPDATE**

This script I've in classA.php file , and its encoding is default like default.php file encoding. I just added in default.php file in first line this

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

but it still doesn't work.

**Third update**

sql =>

```
create table ok(
id int(2) not null auto_increment primary key,
name varchar(20) charset utf8 not null);
```

and php file

```
<?php
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
        <title>hello</title>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
     <body>


     <?php
        $con = mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","db");

       if (mysqli_connect_errno()==0){
       if ($r = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ok")){
    mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
    while ($d = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){
        echo $d['name'] . "<br>";
           }
           }
          }

            if (isset($con)){
               mysqli_close($con);
             }
             ?>


               </body>
               </html>
```

I've inserted in ok table this=>

```
insert into ok(name) values("one"),("ერთი"),("two"),("ორი");
```

PS. special characters are Georgian :)

and it results English characters fine and Georgians with question marks :(

It doesn't work anyways :(

Comment: how are you retrieving it and how are you "encoding is utf8"?

Comment: I'm retrieving it with php script, want to post this script too ? .php file encoding is utf8 too , when I'm typing foreign letters it is saving and showing , but when I am trying to retrieve from database it shows me quesiton marks

Comment: do you: SET CHARACTER SET utf8   SET NAMES utf8   ini_set( "default_charset", "UTF-8");

Comment: no , in php.ini it is default: latin1

Comment: look at the answers by Nadav S. and Mihai Stancu

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact that **the PHP file is in UTF-8** doesn't necessarily mean that the data coming from/ going to the **database** is in UTF-8 too.

You didn't mention which extension you're using, but:

- For **mysql** use `mysql_set_charset($link,'utf8');`
- For **mysqli** use `mysqli->set_charset('utf8')` or the same as above with `mysqli_`
- For **PDO**, when you connect include `charset:utf8` in the **DSN** string.

Comment: Not coming as UTF8 does not prevent transfer as UTF8. It prevents you from doing proper utf8 multi-byte operations on the string.

Comment: I agree that `charset:utf8` should be used because it will solve other problems that may arise later-on when processing the data in PHP before sending it to the client/ browser. But the issue here is the fact that the client/ browser does not know what encoding should be used.

Comment: @MihaiStancu interesting. Let's wait for the questioner.

Comment: I'm using mysqli extension , so is it necessary to define mysqli->set_charset('utf8') in php script ?

Comment: @Tornike Yes, it is necessary, but you don't have to use OOP style if you don't want to, you can also use `mysqli_set_charset()`. [Documentation>>](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)

Comment: I've understood this , but please see the my question once again , I'll update it now , I'm new for this stuff and can't doing it well :)

Comment: @Tornike I've seen your edited question. Try to use `parent::set_charset()` instead?

Comment: How I understood it is provokes problems to change file encoding to utf8 especially in BOM , so if I do not change and I want to write in this file simple (directly into html) special characters Do I've to use this kind of codes &#4304; ?

Comment: I didn't really understand, if you want to write special HTML characters use `html_special_chars($output)`, but it's not instead of setting the character set.

Comment: I beg you once again look at my third update , I'm confused why can not doing it

Comment: @Tornike your code seems to be fine. Can you show us the app itself?

Comment: @Tornike - Set the charset directly after creating the database connection (before you make a query). You can insert the UTF-8 encoded string directly in a UTF-8 encoded PHP page without converting it to HTML entities (&#4304;).

Answer (score 3):

Declare the HTML utf8 encoding:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

And/ Or transfer encodings in the headers:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Comment: The file may be saved from his text editor as UTF8, that does not mean that the transfer encoding is UTF8

Comment: this header should be in the .php file where is written data retrieving php script ?

Comment: The header should be in the PHP that returns the data to the browser.

Comment: It's OK to have latin1 encoding in your PHP files. And it should work just fine as long as you don't use multi-byte characters within the source code (and even then it should work it would just display them wrong in your text editor).

Comment: The BIG issue is not to have some files saved as UTF8, and others as latin1, and especially not to use Unicode UTF8 with BOM. Because BOM especially and different encodings particularly may yield some characters when including each other.  That means that including a Class file may echo the BOM/ Other missinterpreted encoding and thus make you unable to use redirects because that character was sent to the browser and you get the classic "headers already sent" error. Debugging is a dread in that case because you don't know which file was saved with different encoding/ where the inclusion is.

Comment: I've understood that ,but if I don't change it file encoding , how can I simple write with special characters in this file ?

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
htmlentities($row['name'],ENT_QUOTES);
```

see **[`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)**

Comment: That does not fix the problem, it sweeps it under the rug. But if your special characters are not outside of the defined entities spectrum it works.